# Problems when drawing scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib.pyplot.scatter to draw some simple scatter plot. However, something wrong appears and I cannot find the solution. Here is the code  for drawing this scatter plot:

```
 # xActA, yActA, xActQ, yActQ are all lists with same dimensions.
ax1 = scatter(xActA, yActA, color = 'blue',s = 20, label = 'Answers', linestyle = 'o')
ax2 = scatter(xActQ, yActQ, color = 'black', s = 20, label = 'Questions', linestyle = 'o')
ax1.set_label('Answers')
ax2.set_label('Questions')
xscale('log')
yscale('log')
title('User activity')
xlabel('Number of posts')
ylabel('Number of users')
legend()
f1.show()
f1.savefig('figure7_test.png')
```

And there is no error but the plot does not contain any dots.

[image]

Here is the data:

```
xActA = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 129, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
             18, 147, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
             35, 36, 39, 40, 7, 45, 46, 49, 50, 52, 53, 183, 59, 63, 65, 69,
             70, 72, 73, 55, 77, 78, 84, 85, 43, 215, 88, 100, 94, 131, 167,
             19, 375, 122, 125, 149]

  len(xActA) = 70

  yActA = [1212, 822, 194, 94, 61, 44, 24, 1, 26, 20, 11, 16, 10, 8, 5, 8,
             5, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
             31, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
             1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]

  len(yActA) = 70

  xActQ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,    24, 25, 29, 36, 40, 45, 48, 50, 55, 67, 124]
  len(xActQ) = 34

  yActQ [204, 242, 150, 50, 49, 27, 5, 9, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 8, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
  len(yActQ) = 24
```

And the second error is raised by using another data set. I am checking the data...Sorry for the previous unclear description.

Comment: For the second issue (the one resulting in `setting an array element with a sequence`), it will help if you edit the question to show what the contents -- or some subset of the contents -- of `xRa` and `yRa` are.

Comment: Why are you using `scatter` for this?  Scatter is intended to plot 3 or 4 dimensional data in 2 dimensions (by varying color and/or size).  You just need `plot`.  Other than that, it appears that you're leaving out a good deal of the code to produce the figure you show in your image. The code snippet you have works (other than the `linestyle='o'` part as @David already pointed out).  You're leaving out the part of your code that is causing your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your point. Actually I am realizing a plot I saw and I just guess it is using scatter. And yes, you are right, the plot can show exactly the same after I tried since the legend appears two dots instead of three using scatter. However, I am still curious why there is nothing in my scatter plot...

Comment: Opinion: I suggest for future questions that you keep the original question "intact" and ask new questions that you have in new SO questions. This question has had at least three major stages during its life and the current question looks too little like the original. The result of that is that my answer and several of the comments appear tangential (or even distracting) in the context of the current question, which will disorient new users arriving to view this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closer at your data you will notice that most of your data points fall outside of the plot area (x=[1e2:1e3]; y=[1e2:1e4]). If you use a linear scale instead of a logarithmic scale you will see some scatter points, however, not in a very readable manner. But if you change your scale to 'symlog' and then set the x and y limits using 'xlim' and 'ylim', your done. Of course you have to make sure that the marker is set to 'o' when running 'scatter'. Check the full code.

```
from pylab import *

# The data
xActA = array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 129, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
    18, 147, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 
    39, 40, 7, 45, 46, 49, 50, 52, 53, 183, 59, 63, 65, 69, 70, 72, 73, 55, 77,
    78, 84, 85, 43, 215, 88, 100, 94, 131, 167, 19, 375, 122, 125, 149])
yActA = array([1212, 822, 194, 94, 61, 44, 24, 1, 26, 20, 11, 16, 10, 8, 5, 8, 
    5, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 31, 2, 1,
    1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2,
    1, 1, 1, 1])

xActQ = array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 29, 36, 40, 45, 48, 50, 55, 67, 124])
yActQ = array([204, 242, 150, 50, 49, 27, 5, 9, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 8, 4, 5, 1, 3, 
    3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

# The plots
close('all')
f1 = figure()
ax1 = scatter(xActA, yActA, color='blue', s=20, label='Answers', marker='o')
ax2 = scatter(xActQ, yActQ, color='black', s=20, label='Questions', marker='o')
xscale('symlog')
yscale('symlog')
xlim([0, 1e3])
ylim([0, 1.5e3])
title('User activity')
xlabel('Number of posts')
ylabel('Number of users')
legend()
f1.show()
f1.savefig('figure7_test.png')
```

And these couple of lines of code give you this neat figure: [image: Results]
<sub>(source: [nublia.com](https://www.nublia.com/dev/stackoverflow/figure7_test.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with `linestyle='o'`. The `'o'` directive is a `marker`, not a `linestyle`, so replace `linestyle` with `marker` in your first two lines of code.

You can see the complete list of markers for `scatter` [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried, and it just turns to the second mistake again. I have posted the content of xRa and yRa. Could you help me to find the mistake? :)

Comment: @AnneS Using the data you added to the question, I am not able to reproduce the exception you are getting for the second part of the question. The call to `scatter` in your question passes `xRa` and `yRa`, but you edited to include `xActA` and `yActA`. Are those two sets of variables the same?

Comment: I am sorry, I use the different names. Yes, these two sets of variables are same.

Comment: I update the question...I am sorry for the unclear statement. Could you find out why there is no real plot in my figure?

Comment: @AnneS It looks like regeirk addressed that issue.